# Fourier Series Expansion, error in coefficients?

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

After reworking the problem many times I keep getting the same (incorrect?) answer.

So the problem as stated is

> Find the Fourier expansion of :
>   $$
> f(x) = \begin{cases} 
>     x &\text{ if }0 < x < \pi,\\ 
>     2(\pi - x) &\text{ if }\pi < x < 2\pi
> \end{cases}
> $$

I get the following Fourier coefficients:
\begin{align}
a_0 &= \frac{-π}{4}
\\
a_n &= \frac{ 1 - (-1)^n}{π n^2}
\\
b_n &= \frac{4 + 3(-1)^n}{n}
\end{align}

They are apparently wrong since I'm meant to show that
$$
\frac{π^2}{8} = \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{(2n-1)^2}
$$

I've checked the jump discontinuities $ \frac{1}{2(f^+(\pi) + f^-(\pi))}$ and $\frac{1}{2(f^+(2\pi) + f^-(2\pi))}$ so it can only be an error in my coefficients?

Comment: Are you sure that the second case is not $(2\pi-x)$ so that the function is continuous and $b_n=0$?

Comment: I reworked the problem with (2π−x) but still it does not give the required answer. Its for an assignment, counts minimal marks but still.... Should I tell the Prof its a nonsense question? And thanks for all your help LutzL.

Comment: The idea is to write out the series at $x=\pi$, and it is a standard trick, should give no problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the shifted variant $f(x)=\pi-|x|$ on $[-π,π]$ as fundamental period.

Then, since it is an even function, $b_n=0$ and 
\begin{align}
a_0&=\frac1{\pi}\int_0^\pi(\pi-x)dx\\&=\frac1{2\pi}[-(\pi-x)^2|_0^\pi=\frac{\pi}2
\\
a_n&=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^\pi(\pi-x)\cos(nx)dx
\\&=\frac2{n\pi}[(\pi-x)\sin(nx)]_0^\pi+\frac2{n\pi}\int_0^\pi \sin(nx)\\
&=\frac2{n^2\pi}[-\cos(nx)]_0^\pi=\frac{2(1-(-1)^n)}{n^2\pi}
\end{align}
which implies $a_{2n}=0$ and $a_{2n+1}=\frac4{(2n+1)^2\pi}$

Comparing function and series at $x=0$ gives
$$
\pi=f(0)=\frac\pi2+\frac4\pi\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{(2n+1)^2}
$$
which rearranged leads to 
$$
\frac{\pi^2}{8}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{(2n+1)^2}
$$

Comment: Thanks again LutzL. Nowhere in my study guide or the prescribed text book is the method described, or even mentioned. I dont mind hard questions but questions such as these are rather annoying. Could you recommend a text book?